# Nested Querying in Mongoid in 2013

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, mongoid3, subquery

So this question is two years old:

[Querying embedded objects in Mongoid/rails 3 ("Lower than", Min operators and sorting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259121/querying-embedded-objects-in-mongoid-rails-3-lower-than-min-operators-and-so)

and the way it recommends to query nested objects with less than or greater than:

```
current_user.trips.where('start.time' => {'$gte' => Time.now}).count
```

simply doesn't work, it returns 0 for the numerous queries I have like this which is wrong. I've also tried

```
current_user.trips.where(:'start.time'.gte => Time.now}).count
```

which is also 0. None of these actually throw an error.

What is the correct syntax for querying nested elements nowadays? Seems to be a fair bit of confusion over this.

Comment: Deleted my answer so that others try to answer, sorry I could not help...

Comment: @Sparda its grand, thanks for helping, your original answer seemed close

Answer (score 2):

It works as you expect in my environment. (mongoid 3.1.3)

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :trips
end

class Trip
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_one :start
  embedded_in :user
end

class Start
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :time, type: DateTime
  embedded_in :trip
end

User.create({ trips: [
  Trip.new({ start: Start.new({ time: 5.days.ago }) }),
  Trip.new({ start: Start.new({ time: 2.days.from_now }) })
] })

current_user = User.where({}).first

p current_user.trips.where('start.time' => {'$gte' => Time.now}).count
p current_user.trips.where(:'start.time'.gte => Time.now).count
```

The above code outputs the following:

```
1
1
```

Is `$gte` really correct?  It is a common mistake to use the opposite sign when comparing dates.

Or it might be because you are using older version of Mongoid.

**Update:**

You can check queries Mongoid generates with the following code:

```
Mongoid.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
Moped.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
Mongoid.logger = Logger.new($stdout)
Moped.logger = Logger.new($stdout)
```

This is useful for debugging.

Comment: Thanks for answering :) I don't want to use embeds_one/embedded_in, rather I'm using has_one/belongs_to, don't think thats causing the problem. Version is the same, still giving me back zero, even when `current_user.trips.first.start.time` is fine...

Comment: `has_one` is different from `embeds_one`.  MongoDB doesn't support Join operation.  Outputting logs of Mongoid will help you understand the difference.

Comment: Oh I know that, thats why I pointed it out! That could be it.

Comment: Nested querying which uses `has_one`/`has_many` relation is impossible in MongoDB.  This is a limitation of MongoDB and even Object Document Mapper cannot solve it.