# Mongoid - Query nested objects and match with array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, nested, mongodb-query, mongoid4

My models

```
class Person
  embeds_many :skills, class_name: "PersonSkill"

class Project
  embeds_many :skills, class_name: "ProjectSkill"

class Skill
  belongs_to :tag # Tag class is irrelevant for my question I think
  field :tag_name # Assume it's synchronised with tag.name

class PersonSkill < Skill
  embedded_in :person

class ProjectSkill < Project
  embedded_in :project
```

Now I need to build a few queries/scope. The idea is that projects have many skills, and the Project managers want to be able to find a list of people who do have those skills

Basically : several skills [skillA, skillB, skillC] are associated to project A. A project manager wants to find people with

- skillA AND skillB
- skillA OR skillB
- (skillA AND skillB) or (skillA AND skillC)

Is it possible to define some nice mongoid scopes that would let me do that easily?

I had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259121/querying-embedded-objects-in-mongoid-rails-3-lower-than-min-operators-and-so) and I came up with the following scope, but it only covers one of the 3 cases mentionned above.

```
scope :with_skills, ->(tag_ids){where('competences.tag_id' => {'$in' => tag_ids})}
```